# Str.find() unable to search for '\n'

Tags: python, string

I am trying to extract text between two keywords using `str.find()`. But it fails to find the occurrence of '\n'

```
text = 'Cardiff, the 6th November 2007\n company \n'
String_to_extract = '6th November 2007'
keywords = {'date': ['Cardiff, the ' , '\n']}
```

Code:

```
text2=text[text.find(keywords['date']0])+len(keywords[0]):text.find(keywords['date'][1])]
print(text2)

str.find() is unable to search for '\n', which results in no output
```

PS-Want to use `str.find()` method only

Comment: why you are using key ? I assume you wanted to use date as keyword or am I wrong ?

Comment: @Docaro Editing should not be used to correct a person's mistakes- leave a comment or answer instead

Comment: I've noticed you edited the question with the corrections from my answer. An upvote/accept of my answer would be proper ...

Comment: @DavidDeprost OP hasn't, someone else has. I am rolling back the edit

Comment: Ah ok, thanks for the support. But it seems OP has now re-edited your rollback ;)

Comment: Hi, Can someone please have a look at the question, I have addressed the problem more specifically now.

Answer (score 1):

You've incorrectly calculated first index. Try this:

```
text = 'Cardiff, the 6th November 2007\n\n company \n\n'
keywords = ['Cardiff, the ', '\n']

result = text[text.find(keywords[0])+len(keywords[0]):text.find(keywords[1])]
```

Output:

```
6th November 2007
```

Comment: Could you please try you logic on this string text = 'Cardiff, the 6th November 2007\n\n company \n\n'

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here:

- In the `keywords` dictionary you use a `date` variable that should be string: `'date'`.
- In the `keywords` dictionary you doubly escaped `\\n`, while you don't do this in the `text` variable.
- In the index calculations you use a `key` variable that is defined no where; this should be the `'date'` key defined in the `keywords` dictionary.
- And finally, you calculate the starting position of the first index, while it should be the ending position.

Try this:

```py
# String to be extracted = '6th November 2007'
text = 'Cardiff, the 6th November 2007\n\n \n\n'
keywords = {'date' : ['Cardiff, the ' , '\n\n']}

a = text.find(keywords['date'][0]) + len(keywords['date'][0])
b = text.find(keywords['date'][1])
text2 = text[a:b]
print(text2)
```

Answer (score 0):

To generalize the Answer. use this Code:

```
text2 = text[text.find(keywords[key][0])+len(keywords[key][0]):text.find(keywords[key][1])] # you can replace the key with whatever you want as keys
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a really interesting question, and goes to show how something trivial may become hard to find if used in chained manner. Let's see what's happening in your code. You say that your code can't seem to find the 1st occurrence, however, I would like to state the opposite, it definitely finds the first occurrence. In the text: `'Cardiff, the 6th November 2007\n\n \n\n'` you are trying to find the first occurrence of `'Cardiff, the '`. You will see that in the text, the index of the string starts from index 0, i.e. `text[0]`. so this code `text[text.find(keywords[key][0]):text.find(keywords[key][1])]` essentially becomes `text[0:text.find(keywords[key][1])]`. Now in Python slicing rule, 0 is inclusive and you are getting the output like `Cardiff, the 6th November 2007` and thinking it did not find the first occurrence. So in order to fix it, you need to move start slicing from after `'Cardiff, the '`. You can achieve this by altering the text2 assignment in this way:

```
text2 = text[text.find(keywords[key][0])+len(keywords[key][0]):text.find(keywords[key][1])]
```

There are other ways to achieve what you want, but this what you were trying to do originally.